# Cannot build tensor flow C++ windows 10, cannot find numpy

Tags: python, c++, windows, tensorflow, build

I'm following [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) to install tensorflow and I'm currently stuck at:
`bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` (CPU only in the page I've linked)

The error I'm getting

```
INFO: Repository 'png_archive' used the following cache hits instead of downloading the corresponding file.
 * Hash 'e45ce5f68b1d80e2cb9a2b601605b374bdf51e1798ef1c2c2bd62131dfcf9eef' for http://mirror.tensorflow.org/github.com/glennrp/libpng/archive/v1.6.34.tar.gz
If the definition of 'png_archive' was updated, verify that the hashes were also updated.
INFO: Repository 'cython' used the following cache hits instead of downloading the corresponding file.
 * Hash 'bccc9aa050ea02595b2440188813b936eaf345e85fb9692790cecfe095cf91aa' for http://mirror.tensorflow.org/github.com/cython/cython/archive/0.28.4.tar.gz
If the definition of 'cython' was updated, verify that the hashes were also updated.
INFO: Repository 'eigen_archive' used the following cache hits instead of downloading the corresponding file.
 * Hash '048c7e33df1f1eab470e4b09f14c9ed508b91cb813750b4be2c012991363e735' for http://mirror.tensorflow.org/bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/48dfc9c91096.tar.gz
If the definition of 'eigen_archive' was updated, verify that the hashes were also updated.
INFO: Repository 'icu' used the following cache hits instead of downloading the corresponding file.
 * Hash 'e15ffd84606323cbad5515bf9ecdf8061cc3bf80fb883b9e6aa162e485aa9761' for http://mirror.tensorflow.org/github.com/unicode-org/icu/archive/release-62-1.tar.gz
If the definition of 'icu' was updated, verify that the hashes were also updated.
ERROR: D:/machinelearning/tensorflow/third_party/py/numpy/BUILD:11:1: no such package '@local_config_python//': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:/machinelearning/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 344
                _create_local_python_repository(repository_ctx)
        File "D:/machinelearning/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 296, in _create_local_python_repository
                _get_numpy_include(repository_ctx, python_bin)
        File "D:/machinelearning/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 276, in _get_numpy_include
                _execute(repository_ctx, [python_bin, "-c",..."], <2 more arguments>)
        File "D:/machinelearning/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 56, in _execute
                _fail("\n".join([error_msg.strip() if ... ""]))
        File "D:/machinelearning/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 27, in _fail
                fail(("%sPython Configuration Error:%...)))
Python Configuration Error: Problem getting numpy include path.

Is numpy installed?
 and referenced by '//third_party/py/numpy:headers'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 77.530s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```

However if I run `pip list` I get:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
numpy      1.16.2
pip        19.0.3
setuptools 40.8.0
```

Which means numpy is installed. Can you suggest a way to carry on the building?

Thanks

Comment: Hi,

Have you solve this problem? I have the same issue, please let me know how to solve the problem. Thanks